# Por que el ciclo for en Java se ejecuta dos veces

Tags: java, postgresql

Resulta que tengo esta funcion que contiene este ciclo for en Java que hace registros de las filas en el JTable hasta la base de datos

```
public void registrarResultado() {
       DefaultTableModel tbl_model = (DefaultTableModel) vista.tabla_estudiantes.getModel();
      String materia = vista.tabla_materia.getModel().getValueAt(vista.tabla_materia.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();

        int rows = tbl_model.getRowCount(); // ESTO ES IGUAL A 3
        int columns = tbl_model.getColumnCount()-1; // ESTO ES IGUAL A 4

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 3; j < columns; j++) {
                String cedula = tbl_model.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
                double ponderacion = Double.parseDouble(tbl_model.getValueAt(i, j).toString());
                String codigo_examen = tbl_model.getColumnName(j);
                modelo = new resultado(materia, cedula,  codigo_examen,  ponderacion); 
                modelo.registrarResultado();
            }
        }

    }
```

Estos son los datos en el JTable

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y estos son los datos que llegan a la BD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Almacena los datos correctamente, sin embargo, los duplica ya que ejecuta el ciclo for dos veces y no entiendo porque, es decir, cuando el primer ciclo de filas (rows) llega a 3 el hace un corte, porque obviamente deberia quebrar la ejecucion del ciclo ya que cumplio las condiciones, pero luego se vuelve a ejecutar desde cero otra vez y ejecuta todo lo de adentro nuevamente, pero lo extrano es que lo hace dos veces, y no entiendo por que.

Comment: Por qué haces dos for? yo agregaría esto if(j==3){break;}

Comment: No creas que no lo intente, ya lo hice, sin embargo, no ha servido de nada porque el ciclo for se ejecuta la segunda vez obviando todos los datos del ciclo anterior, por lo tanto, asi como el ciclo for se ejecuta dos veces, ese codigo que tu propones lo ejecuta dos veces. Hago dos for por que es una matriz, la cual tiene filas y columnas, y asi es como se recorre una matriz con ciclos

Comment: Aunque estoy de acuerdo que no le veo sentido al segundo bucle, para mi el problema debe ser simplemente que el método `registrarResultado()` es ejecutado 2 veces. Pero francamente, para este tipo de preguntas, tu eres el que estás en el mejor lugar para depurar el problema por medio de ir siguiendo lo que usa usando el modo Debug y poniendo breakpoints.

Comment: Totalmente, he hecho ya los breakpoints, por eso estoy seguro que el metodo `registrarResultado()` no se ejecuta dos veces, es el primer ciclo for que cuando llega a tres, hace el break, pero luego continuando la depuracion, vuelve a entrar al ciclo inicandolo de nuevo, y de verdad, me quedo impresionado por que no deberia ser asi, y no veo que tenga algun error aparente en las variables

Comment: porque no le ves sentido al segundo bucle???

Comment: creo que he sido un idiota, pense que me hablablas del metodo `modelo.registrarResultado()`, es el principal. Voy a revisar que sucede.

Comment: No debe iterar una vez, por que en la linea `double ponderacion = Double.parseDouble(tbl_model.getValueAt(i, j).toString());` si te fijas estoy obteniendo un valor de una interseccion

Comment: No, por que el usuario puede agregar columnas de manera dinamica, es decir, el puede tener muchas columnas de ponderacion al lado de la que esta, solo que en el ejemplo la hice con una sola columna

Comment: Ah ok, entendido.

Comment: Cuando te ocurran cosas como estas prueba el código de una forma muy sencilla. Por ejemplo: `int rows = 3; int columns = 4; for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) { for (int j = 3; j < columns; j++) { System.out.println(j); } System.out.println(i); }`. En esa prueba el código funciona, Se ejecuta 3 veces en cada bucle. Entonces no es problema de los `for`. El problema es: **(A)** o que `rows` y `columns` no tienen los valores que crees que tienen, o **(B)** que algo raro pasa en esta llamada: `modelo.registrarResultado();` Revisa bien esa dos cosas.

Comment: @AnthonyMedina ¿puedes mostrar cómo mandas llamar tu primer método `registrarResultado()`? Como los demás, creo que estás mandando llamar dos veces este método, no estoy hablando de `modelo.registrarResultado()`.